# Ubuntu 14.04 slow (after update?)

Tags: 14.04, htop

After an update, my Desktop slows down a lot. Linux commands and reboot now take a lot of time. Chrome is unusable.

dmesg output right after reboot

```
[    1.706897] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[    1.739718]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3
[    1.739910] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    1.742924]  sdb: sdb1
[    1.743285] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[    2.409071] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[    8.571900] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[   18.426637] EXT4-fs (sda2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[  192.814910] Adding 33200124k swap on /dev/sda3.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:33200124k FS
[  200.721474] systemd-udevd[351]: starting version 204
[  204.654877] video: unknown parameter 'use_native_backlight' ignored
[  204.655379] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[  204.663177] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[  204.749990] AVX2 version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[  204.749992] AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
[  204.767227] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
[  206.670827] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[  219.042840] [drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 2048M
[  219.042842] checking generic (e0000000 300000) vs hw (e0000000 10000000)
[  219.042843] fb: switching to inteldrmfb from EFI VGA
[  219.042900] Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25
[  219.042946] [drm] Replacing VGA console driver
[  219.048336] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[  219.048337] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[  219.048640] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:00:02.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
[  219.078401] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[  219.078490] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
[  219.078505] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[  219.079421] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[  219.079684] acpi device:5d: registered as cooling_device9
[  219.079748] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input8
[  219.079828] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20151010 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[  220.161349] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[  220.161423] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[  220.168798] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
[  220.168801] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain core
[  220.168802] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain uncore
[  220.168804] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain dram
[  220.224673] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0: autoconfig for ALC892: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:line
[  220.224675] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[  220.224676] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x1b/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[  220.224677] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[  220.224677] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    dig-out=0x1e/0x0
[  220.224678] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    inputs:
[  220.224679] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Front Mic=0x19
[  220.224680] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Rear Mic=0x18
[  220.224681] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Line=0x1a
[  220.235660] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input9
[  220.235764] input: HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input10
[  220.235843] input: HDA Intel PCH Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input11
[  220.235898] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[  220.238305] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input12
[  220.238355] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input13
[  220.270339] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input14
[  220.270385] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input15
[  220.270458] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input16
[  251.265339] systemd-udevd[367]: timeout: killing '/usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/var/run/alsa restore 1' [539]
[  251.265433] systemd-udevd[367]: '/usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/var/run/alsa restore 1' [539] terminated by signal 9 (Killed)
[  251.300077] systemd-udevd[369]: timeout: killing '/usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/var/run/alsa restore 0' [541]
[  251.300179] systemd-udevd[369]: '/usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/var/run/alsa restore 0' [541] terminated by signal 9 (Killed)
[  276.765663] EXT4-fs (sda2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[  279.289123] EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[  291.375034] init: failsafe main process (763) killed by TERM signal
[  313.048667] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[  313.048674] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[  313.048675] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[  313.048677] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[  313.048679] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[  313.048681] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[  313.060312] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  313.060316] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  313.060318] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  317.562364] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  317.562366] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  317.562368] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  346.065281] init: avahi-cups-reload main process (870) terminated with status 1
[  386.129312] audit: type=1400 audit(1505802272.153:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=936 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  386.148019] audit: type=1400 audit(1505802272.169:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=916 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  386.148253] audit: type=1400 audit(1505802272.169:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=916 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  386.162989] audit: type=1400 audit(1505802272.185:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=933 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  386.190349] audit: type=1400 audit(1505802272.213:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=929 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  386.190621] audit: type=1400 audit(1505802272.213:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=929 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  386.190857] audit: type=1400 audit(1505802272.213:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=929 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  386.204737] audit: type=1400 audit(1505802272.225:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=928 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  386.205003] audit: type=1400 audit(1505802272.225:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session//chromium" pid=928 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  386.229703] systemd-journald[942]: Failed to resolve 'systemd-journal' group: No such process
[  386.236127] audit: type=1400 audit(1505802272.257:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=934 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  429.172018] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[  429.411029] audit_printk_skb: 36 callbacks suppressed
[  429.411031] audit: type=1400 audit(1505802315.433:24): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=1019 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  430.749664] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[  430.749667] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[  430.749695] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[  599.378881] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[  599.381710] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (1537) terminated with status 1
[  599.381716] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[ 3950.349712] traps: unity-panel-ser[2625] trap int3 ip:7f8d68d2fc13 sp:7ffec2376550 error:0
```

full output https://paste.ubuntu.com/25570962/

My desktop spec is not bad actually.

```
sudo lshw -short
H/W path       Device     Class          Description====================================================
                          system         To Be Filled By O.E.M. (To Be Filled By O.E.M.)
/0                        bus            B85 Pro4
/0/0                      memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/d                      memory         256KiB L1 cache
/0/e                      processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz
/0/e/f                    memory         1MiB L2 cache
/0/e/10                   memory         8MiB L3 cache
/0/11                     memory         32GiB System Memory
/0/11/0                   memory         8GiB DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
/0/11/1                   memory         8GiB DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
/0/11/2                   memory         8GiB DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
/0/11/3                   memory         8GiB DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
/0/100                    bridge         4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller
/0/100/2                  display        Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
/0/100/3                  multimedia     Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller
/0/100/14                 bus            8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI
/0/100/16                 communication  8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
/0/100/19      eth0       network        Ethernet Connection I217-V
/0/100/1a                 bus            8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2
/0/100/1b                 multimedia     8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller
/0/100/1c                 bridge         8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1
/0/100/1c.2               bridge         82801 PCI Bridge
/0/100/1c.2/0             bridge         ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge
/0/100/1d                 bus            8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1
/0/100/1f                 bridge         B85 Express LPC Controller
/0/100/1f.2               storage        8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode]
/0/100/1f.3               bus            8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
/0/1           scsi0      storage        
/0/1/0.0.0     /dev/sda   disk           3TB ST3000DM001-1ER1
/0/1/0.0.0/1              volume         511MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/1/0.0.0/2   /dev/sda2  volume         2762GiB EXT4 volume
/0/1/0.0.0/3   /dev/sda3  volume         31GiB Linux swap volume
/0/2           scsi2      storage        
/0/2/0.0.0     /dev/sdb   disk           3TB HGST HDN724030AL
/0/2/0.0.0/1   /dev/sdb1  volume         2794GiB EXT4 volume
/0/3           scsi3      storage        
/0/3/0.0.0     /dev/sdc   volume         2794GiB HGST HDN724030AL
/1             ham0       network        Ethernet interface
```

RAM and CPU usage looks fine according to [htop](https://ibb.co/iWhTZQ).
[image]

Is there any indication why it is so slow?

Thanks in advance.

Simon